# Improve upon duplication check code in batch

Tags: performance, batch-file, for-loop, random, duplicates

This bit of code works great! But is there any way to make it faster? Currently, it outputs fine, but with a slight delay as it is creating and deleting files quite frequently. In the end, the goal is to get it to stop duplicates and it does that but how can it be done more efficiently?

Code:

```
@echo off

SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

goto :start

:attackers
set i=0
for %%a in (Vigil Ela Lesion Mira Echo Caviera Valkyrie Frost Mute
            Smoke Castle Pulse Doc Rook Jager Bandit Tachanka Kapkan) do (
   set /A i+=1
   set operator[!i!]=%%a
)
set /a operator=%random%%%i+1
set operator=!operator[%operator%]!
if not exist "ops\" mkdir ops\
if exist ops\%operator%.txt (goto :attackers)
copy /y NUL ops\%operator%.txt >NUL
exit /B

:start
for /l %%x in (1, 1, 5) do (
call :attackers
echo !operator!
)
pause
del /q ops\
goto :start
```

Comment: Every time you call attackers it recreates the array. In a previous question of yours I showed you how not to do that. This will improve the speed sightly.

Comment: Perhaps this question suits better on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code change runs instantaneously on my 4 year old I5 computer.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

set i=0
for %%a in (Vigil Ela Lesion Mira Echo Caviera Valkyrie Frost Mute
            Smoke Castle Pulse Doc Rook Jager Bandit Tachanka Kapkan) do (
   set /A i+=1
   set operator[!i!]=%%a
)

goto :start

:attackers
set /a rand=%random% %% i + 1
set operator=!operator[%rand%]!
IF NOT DEFINED attackers (set "attackers=#%operator%#" &GOTO :EOF)
if "!attackers:#%operator%#=!"=="%attackers%" (
    set "attackers=#%operator%#%attackers%"
) else (
    GOTO attackers
)
exit /B

:start
set "attackers="
for /l %%x in (1, 1, 5) do (
call :attackers
echo !operator!
)
pause
goto :start
```

Comment: I like how this code does not use the file creation method that I did. With that said, can you explain the:

 `IF NOT DEFINED attackers (set "attackers=#%operator%#" &GOTO :EOF)
if "!attackers:#%operator%#=!"=="%attackers%" (
    set "attackers=#%operator%#%attackers%"
) else (
    GOTO attackers
)`

Comment: @Excallypurr that is the code to make sure it is not using a duplicate.

Comment: Yes, I realize that, but why does it stop duplicates?

Comment: The %attackers% variable is a list of all the randomly selected operators. The IF command is checking to see if the next randomly chosen operator is in the list. If it is not in the list it appends it to the list. If it is in the list it goes back and tries to get another one.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!